# Three.js ignoring fragment shading

Tags: three.js

I am trying to render a "landscape", [with three.js](http://jsfiddle.net/M4UVV/). Now I changed the material for the plane from `MeshBasicMaterial` to `MeshLambertMaterial` or `MeshPhongMaterial` and awaited to get some light effects rendered.
Strangely I see no rendering other than flat.

Can someone tell me, what I am doing wrong or what the actual requirements for Fragment rendering are?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I was missing `plane.computeFaceNormals();`.

I had:

```
plane.computeBoundingSphere();
plane.computeVertexNormals();
```

before and was expecting `computeVertexNormals` to call `computeFaceNormals` implicitly. Seems like this is not the case.
After changing to:

```
plane.computeBoundingSphere();
plane.computeFaceNormals();
plane.computeVertexNormals();
```

lighting works. Is there any documentation about under which circumstances the `compute*` functions need to be called?
And what is `computeVertexNormals` doing, when no face normals were generated yet?

Comment: Yes, whenever you create geometry by hand, or modify geometry.

Comment: When I change the vertice coordinates, it seems to be enough to set `verticesNeedUpdate` and `normalsNeedUpdate`.

Comment: If you change the vertices, you should call to `computeFaceNormals()`/`computeVertexNormals()` too. Depending if you are using `THREE.FlatShading` or `THREE.SmoothShading`.

Comment: I don't think so. Feel free to contribute such explanation.